# array to an array of functions

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

You have an array of arbitrary values. Write a transform function in the global scope that will transform the array to an array of functions that return the original values, so instead of calling a[3], we will call a3.

For example I want:

```
var a = ["a", 24, { foo: "bar" }];
var b = transform(a);

a[1]; // 24
b[1](); // 24
```

However I am getting:

```
b
[function () { 
              return this.temp;
         }, function () { 
              return this.temp;
         }, function () { 
              return this.temp;
         }]
```

Here is my code:

```
var a = ["a", 24, { foo: "bar" }];

var b = transform(a);

document.writeln(a[1]); // 24
document.writeln(b[0]()); // 24
document.writeln(b[1]()); // 24

function transform(array) {

  b = [];
  var i;
     for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        b[i] = function () { 
          return temp;
        };
     }
  return b;
}
```

Comment: Where did `temp` come from? Also, you're not following the spec; isn't the problem to throw functions into the global namespace instead of returning an array? But if that is what you meant to do, and you get to use ES5 methods: `return array.map(function(v) { return function() { return v; }; });`

Answer (score 1):

```
function transform(array) {

  b = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    b[i] = (function (x) { 
              return function () { return x; };
            })(array[i]);
  }
  return b;
}
```

demo  http://jsbin.com/udasoj/1/edit

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have block scope.

Comment: @marszall87 -- because?

Comment: 1. Use of global variable `b`.

2. It's much better to use `Array.prototype.map`.

3. If you really want to mutate array `b`  just use `Array.prototype.push`, not direct assignment.

Comment: @marszall87 -- excellent, thanks.  In my experience no interviewer goes that deep, but very valid points.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct if you call `b[0]()`, then you should get the value returned.

Comment: No, it is not (for various reasons).

Answer (score 0):

What is `temp`? It looks like the way to accomplish this is to generate the function via another function:

```
function transform(array) {
  b = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
     b[i] = createReturnFunction(a[i]);
    };
  }

  return b;
}

function createReturnFunction(value){
  return function(){ return value; }; 
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eFWyf/

Answer (score 0):

Note that none of the existing answers will quite work; they will all produce functions that return that last value in `a`.  `var` is function-scoped and interacts poorly with closures.

See this other answer I just wrote, which explains a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14330595/17875